# TFS 2010 power tools not downloading the latest custom policies to developer machines

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have developed and installed a custom checkin policy dll in windows 2008 server TFS 2010.

I am trying to distribute this dll to developer machines

I followed the instructions as per http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/12/04/distributing-visual-studio-addin-for-the-team/

On click of the Personal Settings-> "Download Now " button, the custom checkin policy is not downloaded to the local machine

No trace of any activity

Is there any configurations I need to change in power tools to download the latest custom checkin policies?